# How to get the default controller url as api url

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

How do I get the default URL as "http://localhost:53037/api/about instead of 
http://localhost:53037/about?

WebAPIConfig.cs:

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

HomeController.cs :

```
 public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult About()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Comment: You could use attribute-based routes where you'd add `[RoutePrefix("api")]` above your method declaration(s)

Comment: Based on your naming convention, they do not seem like API calls but rather presentable web site data.

Comment: You can see this link may be help you to solve that : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/routing-in-aspnet-web-api

Comment: @MarkC. I tried as you suggested but my url displays as http://localhost:53037/home/about instead of http://localhost:53037/api/home/about

Answer (score 0):

Add one more MapHttpRoute Just below the default without api text.

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
       name: "CustomApi",
       routeTemplate: "{controller}/{id}",
       defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
```

Now you can call API with out api text.